# Cant find error (Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Code snippet:

```
dbCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_EVENT_UPATE '" 
    + currentEvent.EventID + "','" + currentEvent.Description + "','" 
    + currentEvent.DisciplineID + "'", dbConnection);
```

Where am I missing a quote?

Answer (score 2):

The un-closed quotation mark is most likely in one of your variables.  Further, building your query like that makes you vulnerable to a sql injection attack.

Look into adding your values using the SqlCommand.Parameters list.

Something like this

```
dbCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_EVENT_UPATE @eventId, @description, @disciplineID", dbConnection);

dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peventId",currentEvent.EventID);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",currentEvent.Description);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disciplineID",currentEvent.DisciplineID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parameters` instead of `hardcoded` strings.

```
using(dbCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
  dbCommand.CommandText="sp_EVENT_UPATE";
  dbCommand.Connection=dbConnection;
  dbCommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID",currentEvent.EventID);
  ....
  dbConnection.Open();
  dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  dbConnection.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your currentEvent.Description could potentially have that single quote which is breaking the syntax of that SQL statement. You should always use prepared statement/commands to counter this kind of scenarios.